# Install python3-venv module on linux mint

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, linux-mint, python-venv

I  was able to move to Linux mint 17.3 64 bit version from my Linux mint 16. This was long awaited migration.

After moving to Linux Mint 17.3, I am not able to the install python3-venv module, which is said to be the replacement for virtualenv in python 3.x. In my linux mint 16 I had access to pyvenv-3.4 tool. I dont know when I installed that module in Linux mint 16.

Anybody faced this issue ?

```
python -m venv test
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available. On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command. After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

izero@Ganesha ~/devel $ sudo apt-get install python3-venv
[sudo] password for izero:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-venv
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.4-venv
```

Then use this:

```
python3 -m venv test
```

the package name is `python3.4-venv` and not `python3-venv`.

Answer (score 12):

For python 3.6 I found out it was a locale issue, running this:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Seems to solve the issue.

Source from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539110/pyvenv-not-working-because-ensurepip-is-not-available) answer

Comment: Important to NOTE: It solved my problem on Ubuntu 16.04.3 Minimal.  (use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale` e it works)

Answer (score 6):

I use python 3.6 , and so the following did the trick for me:
$ sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv

(the problem was that apt-get install python3-venv would virtualenv for 3.5)

Answer (score 2):

1. Update all packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2. Install virtual environment 3

```
apt-get install python3-venv
apt install virtualenv
```

3. Check that it has been installed

```
virtualenv --version
```

*Note: that this is for ubuntu 20 or variants*

Comment: It's worked for me in Linux Mint OS.