# Setting up Beeware: I cannot create my JAR support file within my activated venv

Tags: python, performance, beeware, voc

I've been trying to set up my work environment so I can attempt the Beeware tutorial. 
https://voc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/background/install.html 
I'm following the steps of this installation tutorial using Bash Shell in Windows 8 with Python 3.7. I installed all the relevant software and configured the environmental variables etc.

The problem I encounter happens when I try to create the JAR support file inside my activated venv:

````
$ . env/Scripts/activate
(env) $ cd voc
(env) $ pip install -e .
(env) $ ant java ``` -- at this line of code the shell appears to be endlessly stuck in operation as follows:
````

```
(env) $ ant java
Buildfile: C:\Users\XXXX\tutorial\voc\build.xml

java:

compile:

compile_stdlib:
     [exec] Cloning into 'ouroboros'...
     [exec] Updating files:  17% (340/1941)
```

I've left this running for more than an hour and it shows no sign of progress.

I'm pretty sure that **running the script through the venv is causing the problem** because when I don't use any venv the process runs successfully in just over a minute.**

When I input  the `cd` command, the processes don't appear to change over time either.
I've also tried disabling my windows defender to improve CPU performance with no luck.

Any suggestions are what I can do to get this working in the Venv?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You might want to try with a different environment e.g. on a docker container.**

Here is a report of a try with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as of 2019-11-29. I followed https://voc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/background/install.html

Python 3.7 is used instead of the default 3.6.

```
python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

Java 1.8

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25
```

ant as installed by Ubuntu package manager:

```
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.5 compiled on March 28 2019
```

I had to install the python 3.7 venv see [How to install python3.7 and create a virtualenv with pip on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070868/how-to-install-python3-7-and-create-a-virtualenv-with-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-venv
```

cloning the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/beeware/voc.git
```

activating the virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv env
$ . env/bin/activate
$ cd voc
$ pip install -e .
```

and now finally running the ant command that gave you trouble:

```
ant java
Buildfile: /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/build.xml

java:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/build/java
    [javac] Compiling 140 source files to /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/build/java
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

compile_stdlib:
     [exec] Cloning into 'ouroboros'...
     [exec] Cloning Ouroboros...
     [exec] Compiling 95 python modules...
     [exec] ...............................................................................................
     [exec] Built 95 modules

dist:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/dist
      [jar] Building jar: /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/dist/Python-3.7-Java-support.b7.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/dist

compile:

compile-testdaemon:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/build/java-testdaemon
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/build/java-testdaemon
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
    [javac] 1 warning

dist-testdaemon:
      [jar] Building jar: /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/dist/Python-3.7-Java-testdaemon.b7.jar
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /hd/sengo/home/wf/source/python/beeware/voc/dist

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 56 seconds
```