# How to use neuralcoref in Spacy

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, spacy, coreference-resolution

I have been trying to use the library `neuralcoref`: State-of-the-art coreference resolution based on neural nets and spaCy. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.7.3 in conda 1.9.7 and Spacy 2.2.4.

My code (from the https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref):

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref
    

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)

doc2 = nlp('Angela lives in Boston. She is quite happy in that city.')
for ent in doc2.ents:
    print(ent._.coref_cluster)
```

I have got this error

```
/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: spacy.morphology.Morphology size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 104 from C header, got 112 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: spacy.vocab.Vocab size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 104 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: spacy.tokens.span.Span size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 72 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

I have tried to downgrade the version of Spacy to 2.1.0 as suggested by this [link](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/158):

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
conda install spacy=2.1.0
```

However, I am not able

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - spacy=2.1.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

**How can I solve this issue without downgrade? Is there any new updated version of neuralcoref?**

Comment: I was stuck with the same errors, and was able solve it (I use a mac). I havn't worked with conda in a long time. Have you tried using virtual environment? I am trying to reproduce the error on ubuntu now.

Comment: Also, neuralcoref isn't going to be upgraded from what I have read, I think I remember that they are going to include neuralcoref as part of spaCy 3.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `neuralcoref` to work, you need to use spaCy version `2.1.0` and python version `3.7`. That is the only combination that neuralcored works for on  Ubuntu 16.04 and on Mac.

1. Install python 3.7 on your machine, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070868/how-to-install-python3-7-and-create-a-virtualenv-with-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04)
2. Make sure the selected version of python is 3.7
3. Create your project folder
4. Create a python [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) in your given project folder like so, `python -m venv ./venv`,
5. Install spaCy 2.1.0 like so `python -m pip install spacy==2.1.0`.
6. Install neuralcoref `python -m pip install neuralcoref`

Hope this helps.

---

After running your code above, I get the following output:

```
[My sister: [My sister, She], a dog: [a dog, him]]
Angela: [Angela, She]
Boston: [Boston, that city]
```

Answer (score 3):

Do Precisely what Raqib has said. I used google colab, so skip (1) if using google colab.
Add the following commands:

1)Create a new environment using: (change myenv to the name you want to name the environment to)

```
conda create --name myenv
```

Select that environment:

```
conda info --envs
conda activate myenv
```

2)Then install the python 3.7 in that environment

## Install the python version

```
!apt-get install python3.7
```

3)install spacy and neuralcoref with version supported.

```
!pip install spacy==2.1.0
!pip install neuralcoref
!pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases//download/en_core_web_lg-2.1.0/en_core_web_lg-2.1.0.tar.gz

import pandas as pd
import re
import spacy
import neuralcoref
import en_core_web_lg

nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade to spacy 2

```
pip uninstall -y neuralcoref
pip install --no-cache-dir  neuralcoref --no-binary neuralcoref
pip install -U spacy==2.3.7
python -m spacy download en
```

restart the kernel if you are using jupyter.

and .....

```
import logging;
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
import neuralcoref
```

**update**

```
pip install -U spacy==2.3.7
pip install neuralcoref
python -m spacy download en
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but if you want to use neuralCoref, another option is to use the original version written in Java. The stanza library has a [coreNLP client](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html), which can access original coreNLP models. This doesn't require you to use (an outdated version of) Spacy.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a late answer, today I was digging the internet for the same issue.

At the end of 2022, Spacy has released neuralcoref as a pipeline component. You have to install spacy-experimental for this.

The following links might be helpful:

- https://explosion.ai/blog/coref
- https://spacy.io/api/coref
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fio3BejnRsM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRvAOdrLo6k

The first two links will guide you to the specific technical details. The last two youtube videos will help you use the model in plug-and-play manner.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34669432)