# python3.8-venv not working with python3.8 -m venv env

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I want to create a venv having python3.8 as python3
On Ubuntu 18.04
I did:

```
> sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-venv
```

Now, when I try:

```
> python3.8 -m venv env

The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv   
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/pushp/vizio-backend/env/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

My application depends on python3.8. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try `apt-get install python3-venv` like the error message said? The command you tried is a bit different.

Comment: I did sudo apt purge python3.8-venv. Then, I did sudo apt install python3-venv and got the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyvenv not working because ensurepip is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539110/pyvenv-not-working-because-ensurepip-is-not-available) (procedural conversion of answer into close vote)

Comment: But `Python-3.8` is not in the default apt-repos of Ubuntu-1804("Bionic");  how did you installed it?  To further research please 1) paste the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list(.d/)`, and 2) try to execute the `Failing command: ['/home/pushp/vizio-` from your shell and paste the edit the Q above to include the exception.

Answer (score 31):

Resolved, what I did? :

```
apt install python3.8 python3.8-venv python3-venv
```

Dont know how but installing both the venv packages python3.8-venv python3-venv resolved it from me. Now when I do:

```
python3.8 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
python3 --version
> Python 3.8.0
```

Comment: This did not work for me. python3-venv made no difference.

Comment: I believe this may have "worked around" the problem ONLY because your host system also uses python3.x.  `python3.8-venv` has a problem ...

Comment: What is the source here in line #2, is this just a keyword?

Comment: @Rashid The source command in line 2 is not a keyword. It is a shell command that tells the shell to execute the contents of the file specified after the source keyword. In this case, the file is env/bin/activate. This file is a shell script that sets up the environment variables needed to activate the virtual environment where all your local packages installed using pip are installed locally.

Answer (score 2):

first:
`sudo pip3 install virtualenv`
then `cd` to the directory where you want your virtual environment to be:
`virtualenv "name of env"` for ex: `sudo virtualenv myProject-env`
then to activate:
`sudo source myProject-env/bin/activate`
to make sure that it is work:
`sudo which python`

Answer (score 2):

Installing `python3-distutils` also works around the problem.

Comment: this is the one that i been missing

Answer (score 0):

You might miss the virtual environment installation in your machine.

You can install `virtualenv` using the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv python3-venv
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
```

Answer (score -2):

Referring [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-18-04) document from digitalOcean i got the same error but  here in this line[in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV95C.png) change `python3.6` to `python3.8` then it will work fine.
change `python3.6 -m venv my_env`  to  `python3.8 -m venv my_env`