# Python venv works explicitly with python3.6, but not with python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

## #2 Edit - Solution:

so I found something that fixed it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207387/12291295

if you are getting afterwards a

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

error, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62831268/12291295

I'm trying to create a venv with `python3 -m venv env` or `python3.8 -m venv venv` and I get an error saying :

```
Error: Command '['<some_prior_path>/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

same with python3.8 just `<some_prior_path>/env/bin/python**3.8**`

but if I try `python3.6 -m venv env` it just executes as planned and then I can activate the venv.

#### Version check:

```
python3 -V 

Python 3.8.0
```

#### Things I've tried:

taken from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62815398/12291295

```
sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-venv
```

&

```
apt install python3.8 python3.8-venv python3-venv
```

returns that everything is installed & updated.

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

returns :  `Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (16.7.9)`

and I think the problems lies here, I don't know how to make it to work with every python3 version, I mean why it's not located at `/usr/bin/python3`?

## Edit

it seems like pip installs on default to python3.6 version, and when I try

```
python3.8 -m pip install pip
```

I Get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8: No module named pip
```