# python3.8-venv is no longer working after Pop OS upgraded to 21.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-venv

I'm not able to create any virtual environments for python 3.8 after upgrading to Pop OS 21.04. Getting the following error -

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.8-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.8-venv' has no installation candidate
```

I have already tried adding deadsnakes repo ([blog post](https://dev.to/mortoray/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-1bp4)). Unfortunately, it isn't helping. Also, I found the following info -

```
apt show python3.8
Package: python3.8
Version: 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.10.1
Status: install ok installed
Priority: important
Section: python
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Installed-Size: 521 kB
Depends: python3.8-minimal (= 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.10.1), libpython3.8-stdlib (= 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.10.1), mime-support
Suggests: python3.8-venv, python3.8-doc, binutils
Breaks: python3-all (<< 3.6.5~rc1-1), python3-dev (<< 3.6.5~rc1-1), python3-venv (<< 3.6.5-2)
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.8)
 Python is a high-level, interactive, object-oriented language. Its 3.8 version
 includes an extensive class library with lots of goodies for
 network programming, system administration, sounds and graphics.
```

The `Apt-Sources` item seems a bit strange to me.
The default python version is 3.9.5 in the updated system.

Any idea how this can be resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 2021.1.3 Community Edition
Pop!_OS 21.04
Python 3.9.5

Had exact same issue. This worked for me:
When creating a new project and making a new venv, select python3.9 as the base interpreter (3.8 was the default selection for me).

I can recreate this error by selecting python3.8 when creating a new project.

After receiving the error, I went into directory and deleted the contents of the venv directory. In PyCharm I went to Settings --> Project: [project_name] --> Python Interpreter and created a new venv with python3.9 and no errors, packages install.

Subsequently, I created new projects making sure that python3.9 is selected instead of python3.8 and I do not get errors, additional packages install without issue.

Answer (score 0):

for pop os 21.04

default python version is 3.9.5

it need make install below

```
sudo apt install python3.9-venv -y
```

Answer (score -1):

`venv` is [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) as of Python 3.6. You do not need to install it. Just call:

```
python3.8 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Comment: I wish it had solved the problem - already tried this.

`python3.8 -m venv 38_myenv
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.8-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/.../38_myenv/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']`

Comment: Interesting.... looks a bit like a vicious cycle. Unless you are able to make `ensurepip` available or [fix the environment some other way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539571/6573902).

Comment: Already tried the locale solution, it didn't work. And I can't get `ensurepip` to install for python3.8.
BTW can you throw some light on `Apt-Sources` item ? Seems a bit strange to me. I tried changing it via `apt edit-sources python3.8` but it seems I'm getting the format wrong resulting in a parsing error.