# Unable to create python virtual environment in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

My System-info

- Running Ubuntu Desktop(22.04.1 LTS) from a USB stick
- Base Machine Windows 11
- Python version on Ubuntu is 3.10.4

Trying to create a python virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv .
```

Getting error

```
    The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt install python3.10-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/media/ubuntu/New Volume/myWorks/Ubuntu/DALLE_Project/vnv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

When running the above command

```
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
```

Getting below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.10-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.10-venv' has no installation candidate
```

Getting same above error for `sudo apt install python3-venv` also.

Any suggestion to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

I also searched far and wide when I encountered this problem on my system (Ubuntu 22.04), and none of the suggested solutions worked for me, including:

- Running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` beforehand
- Using `pip` in any form (same error as you had)
- [Exporting and reconfiguring locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539571)

The solution in my case was to (re-)enable the Ubuntu universe repository to be able to install `python3-venv` and related packages, as this was disabled on my machine.

In Ubuntu, this can be done by running the `Software & Updates` tool, which can also be opened by running:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

in the terminal, and then making sure the `Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)` box is ticked (at least in Ubuntu 22.04).

It should prompt you to refresh, after which you can run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install python3-venv`.

I hope this helps.